# AppleScript - determine which folder contains subfolder, knowing only name of subfolder

Tags: applescript

Knowing only name of "unique job number" subfolder, I'm trying to write AppleScript which quickly returns name of "client name" folder which contains my "unique job number" subfolder

**This is my folder structure:**

Client 1

-unique job number

-unique job number

-unique job number

Client 2

-unique job number

-unique job number

-unique job number

**This is my code**

```
tell application "Finder"
    set client_folders to name of folders of folder "2014" of disk "Jobs"
    set counter to 0
    set client_current_folder to "string"
    set my_folder to "TD57706"

    repeat with the_item in client_folders
        set counter to counter + 1
        set client_current_folder to client_folders's item counter
        if (exists folder my_folder of folder client_current_folder of folder "2014" of disk "Jobs") is true then
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    return client_current_folder
end tell
```

This code works fine, but problem is it takes about 2-3 min to execute because I have about 600 client folders. Does anyone have a better idea. It need to take seconds rather than minutes. I was also thinking to create xml of folder structure every morning but folder structure is changing any few minutes as more unique job folders and sometimes clients folders are created.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set client_folders to "/Volumes/Jobs/2014"
set my_folder to "TD57706"
set clientName to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of client_folders & " -type d -name " & quoted form of my_folder & " -exec dirname {} +")
```

Comment: Thanks adayzdone for answer!!! I will try this out and let you know if this works for me.

Comment: Thank you adayzdone. I've marked your answer as accepted answer, because your code works perfectly and it take less than second to find a folder in my Mac. Unfortunately my clients folder structure is on another computer (Windows) in local network and I think this is way my Mac have problem to searche it quickly. I need to run this code on this Windows computer instead on my Mac. Are you able to translate that code to Windows Script and post it here. Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search a Windows disk from your Mac, then mount the Windows disk on the Mac. There is a “mount volume” command in AppleScript. Look in the Standard Additions AppleScript dictionary.